# In C How to use leftmost digit from an integer

Tags: c

I was wondering how to reverse my output to match entered number.
Example if user entered `543210`, I want the output to be: `Five Four Three Two One Zero`. But instead it's reversed and I can't figure out how to reverse it.

> I can't use loops or anything else.

Code:

```
int main(void){
        int value;
        int digit;

        printf("enter:");
        scanf("%i", &value);

        while(value)
        {


                digit = value % 10;
                value = value / 10;

                if(digit != 0)
                {

                        switch(digit)
                        {
                                case 0:
                                        printf("zero ");
                                        break;
                                case 1:
                                        printf("one ");
                                        break;
                                case 2:
                                        printf("two ");
                                        break;
                                case 3:
                                        printf("three ");
                                        break;
                                case 4:
                                        printf("four ");
                                        break;
                                case 5:
                                        printf("five ");
                                        break;
                                case 6:
                                        printf("six ");
                                        break;
                                case 7:
                                        printf("seven ");
                                        break;
                                case 8:
                                        printf("eight ");
                                        break;

                                case 9:
                                        printf("nine ");
                                        break;
                        }
                }

        }

        return 0;

}
```

Exmaple: If user entered 1234
Output would be: four three two one.

How would I fix it to be: One Two Three Four.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept *recursion*, or are you interested in seeing new things?

Comment: Converting them to strings seems to be the most natural way to solve this.

Comment: Store the data into an array of strings instead of directly printing them. once you're done print them in reverse and there you have it. that's the first thing that came to my head but i bet there's an even better solution for this problem.

Comment: Then recursion is indeed your solution. But you're already using a while (just saying)

Comment: Note: you test if digit != 0 and inside that if statement, you do a switch case on digit with the value 0. This is a waste of space, as it is guaranteed not to happen. Remove the if statement, so that the value can still be printed if 0 is entered.

Comment: What about using a stack? Are you allowed to use that?

Comment: strrev is a standard library function used for reversing strings if this helps

Comment: Sorry - I mean array (being rushed with other things sorry about that).

Comment: "I can't use loops or anything else." sounds way to restrictive.  What can you use?

Comment: You could always work from the other end -- divide by 100000000, then by 10000000, then 100000, then 10000 ...  (Keep dividing the divisor by 10.)

Comment: I thought about that, but to me that was quite ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've said that you aren't allowed to use loops, then recursion really is the thing that you are probably being expected to use. I personally am not sure if it would be right to not consider a recursion as a loop, but whatever.

You are using a `while` there, which also is a loop. If you **are** allowed to use loops, then you could just do the following, easy-to-understand modification in your code, and get the output you desire:

```
    ...
    int input;  // <-- added this
    int value;
    int digit;

    printf( "enter:" );
    scanf( "%i", &input );  // <-- notice the change in variable usage

    value = 0;
    while ( input ) {
        value = 10 * value + input % 10;    // adds the last digit of input to value from right
        input /= 10;
    }

    while ( value ) { ... }
    ...
```

If you aren't allowed to use loops, then you probably are expected to use a special function, a function which outputs a specific value for a single case, and returns back to itself in any other case. You need a recursive function. Examine this simple example:

```
// This is in maths, not C
f(x) = 2x + 1   for all integer x >= 0
```

Out of many ways, this one way to describe the function which maps `0` to `1`, then `1` to `3`, then `n` to `2n + 1`. If we wanted to define the exact same function [*recursively*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion):

```
// In maths
f(x = 0) = 1    for x = 0
f(x > 0) = f(x-1) + 2   for integer x > 0
```

You see what's going on in there? It's saying that each subsequent `f(x)` is 2 greater than the previous one `f(x-1)`. But more importantly, the function is calling itself! If you look closer, the called function `f(x-1)` will also call itself:

```
f(x) = f(x-1)         + 2
f(x) = f(x-2) + 2     + 2
f(x) = f(x-3) + 2 + 2 + 2
...
// all these are the same
```

All this calling deeper and deeper has to end somewhere, and that somewhere is when `f(x-...)` is `f(0)`, which has been explicitly defined to be `1`.

This is what recursion is all about. Let me write out the examples I gave above in C:

```
// non-recursive version
int fnonrec( int x ){
    return 2 * x + 1;
}

// recursive version
int frec( int x ){
    if ( x == 0 )
        return 1;   // explicit return value for f(0)
    else    // redundant else, hehe
        return frec( x - 1 ) + 2;
}
```

Definitions of the functions really look similar to how they were defined in maths, don't they? Yeah, well, I don't think giving you the answer for your question would be nice of me. All I can say is that you can print things in reverse really nicely with recursive functions.

Comment: Interesting - I tried it out, and still can't quite get it working right. I'm trying to make it work with the switch statement, and it works however, instead when the user enters: "12345" - I only get the most right digit (5) - Instead of "One Two Three(etc..)).

Comment: @user3470588 It is working on my end... When I input `123`, I get the output `one two three `.

Comment: @CeFu Are you sure that you have written `value = 10 * value + input % 10;` line correctly, or that you haven't accidentally written `input /= 100000;` or something? Here's the proof that it actually works: http://ideone.com/MGNGzq

Comment: I broke my while loop that held  "digit = value % 10"; which caused my error. Thanks for your help! Which I could up vote haha.

Comment: @CeFu You're welcome bro, I hope that I was able to deliver some extra information about recursive functions as well.

Comment: You did actually, it helped strengthen my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

//store user input to `int` variable "`value`"

```
char str[15];

sprintf(str, "%d", value);
```

You can then use the `strrev` function to reverse the string array. Manipulate it from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(int v){
    static char *numbers[] = {
        "zero","one","two","three","four",
        "five","six","seven","eight","nine"
    };
    int digit = v % 10;
    int value = v / 10;
    if(value){
        print(value);
        printf(" %s", numbers[digit]);
    } else 
        printf("%s", numbers[digit]);
}

int main(void){
    int value;

    printf("enter:");
    scanf("%i", &value);
    print(value);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 This is the best solution.  (Could use some explanation for a learner.)

Answer (score 0):

Example using recursive function and numbers from the parameters :

```
#include <stdio.h>

void    display(char c)
 {
  char *numbers[] = {
  "zero","one","two","three","four",
  "five","six","seven","eight","nine "
 };
 printf("%s ", numbers[c]);
}

int     aff_num(char *c)
{
  if (*c == '\0')
    return (0);
  display(*c-48);
  aff_num(++c);
  return (1);
}

int     main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 if (argc < 2)
  {
    printf("Need numbers\n");
    return (-1);
  }
 aff_num(argv[1]);
 return (0);
}
```

Comment: `*c- '0'` is preferable over `*c-48`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a python hacker and I almost never program in C. that being said:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int highest_power_of_ten(int value){
    int exponent = 0;
    int tens = 1;
    while(value > tens){
        tens *= 10;
        exponent += 1;
    }
    return exponent-1;
}
int pow(int base, int exponent){
    if (exponent == 0)
        return 1;
    int temp = base;
    while(exponent > 1){
        base *= temp;
        exponent -= 1;
        }
    return base;
}
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    char* digits[] = 
    {"zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"};
    int value, n, exp, x;
    scanf("%i", &value);

    while(highest_power_of_ten(value)>0){
        exp = highest_power_of_ten(value);
        x = pow(10, exp);
        n = value/x;
        printf("%s ",digits[n]);
        value -= n*x;
    }
    printf("%s\n", digits[value]);
    //system("PAUSE"); for windows i guess
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Another method to get the digits in the right order:

E.g. To get the digit at 1st position in 123 divide 123 by 100, to get 2nd - 123 / 10, to get 3rd 123 / 1. That equals: value / 10^(index of desired digit)
So what we have to do is

1. Get the length of the (remaining) number by calculating log10(value).
2. Then get the (remaining) first (most significant) digit by dividing value by 10^length (length of 1.)
3. calculate value := value - 10^length and start from 1, unless the result is 0 (mind handeling numbers that end on 0).

   ```
   while (value)
   {
       len    = log10(value);
       digit  = (int) value / pow(10, len);
       value -= pow(10, len);
   }
   ```

And your code does never enter case 0. To fix that just leave the if(digit != 0) - that's what I meant when I wrote "mind the 0").

```
if(digit != 0)          // enters if digit is not 0
{
    switch(digit)
    {
        case 0:         // enters if digit is 0
         ...   
    }
}
```

Comment: A more detailed explanation of your answer would be helpful. Newer developers will not necessarily understand the concepts you are trying to convey.

Comment: I edited my post. I hope it's more clearly to understand now.